# Authorization with AD groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm wondering how could I apply a way to give a specific groups on Active Directory the access to the website published internally on IIS.

As I understand since I'm working with core 3.1; this must be done by code inside the application.
and that the web config not needed anymore.

any help/hint/advice would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/?force_isolation=true

Comment: So it works simply by adding to my homeController [Authorize(Roles = "domain\\group")]

Comment: You have to setup groups on the server to work with client.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true